# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'. What should I do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pycharm

I try to recognize objects in images with *imageAI*. I use pycharm, windows 10 64-bit, python 3.6.8. When I try to run my program an error appears:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

It's connected with this string: `import tensorflow as tf`
Also i can send a pic
[image]

## Here's the code:

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

exec_path = os.getcwd()

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath(os.path.join(
    exec_path, 'resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5')
)
detector.loadModel()

    list = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(
        input_image=os.path.join(exec_path, 'objects.jpg'),
        output_image_path=os.os.path.join(exec_path, 'new_objects.jpg')
    )

I have installed with pip tensorflow, pillow, numpy, matplotlib, h5py, keras, image ai, open_cv and scipy.
```

Comment: try to import tensorflow from your terminal / command line in python interactive mood and paste the error then please.

Comment: also - are you sure that this is installed inside exactly this one env which is used by PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Alt+S, then check if tensorflow is added to your project.
Just click project:yourprojectname on the left and then you'll see the list of active modules.
To add the new one, click the plus button on the right and find the tensorflow package.
Choose this one with nothing more in name but tensorflow.
Click install package and wait a little.

I had the same problem with the selenium package. I installed it with pip but for the pycharm, using it's manager is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pycharm it make venv (`virtual environment`) by default so it doesn't matter you pip or install tensorflow on your computer or not, you have to install it again on your `VENV`.

You can use Pycharm *terminal* at the bottom of your IDE(Pycharm) to make sure your `VNEV` is activated then pip your tensorflow.

**Second way** is going to set it on pycahrm Setting (`Ctrl + Alt + S`) , then click on `project` in your setting menu after , then Project Interpreter.
you can add packages here